# Jquery autocomplete not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I know there are several question post about this error, but I cant find any answers that fit my situation. I am in ASP.NET MVC and I am copying an autocomplete function from my partner. It works on his computer, but when I try to use it for a different view, I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

This is the textbox and script:

```
<div id="SearchUser">
            <label>
                Search for user:
                <input type="text" id="usersearch" />
                <input type="button" onclick="addUser()" value="Add" />
            </label>
        </div>
--------------------
//Auto search for users
$(function () {
    $('#usersearch').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserNames")',
                data: { pre: request.term },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Text, value: item.Text };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This same code works on his machine but not mine. I checked the BundleConfig and I do have

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
```

included, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Open chrome developer tools and check if jquery-ui script shows up in the sources tab. My guess is either that or jquery reference is missing.

Comment: That's a relative path to home. Are you sure it exists there? Maybe it should be relative to the current directory? `.` instead of `~`?

Comment: @Sushanth-- jquery-ui is the only one not showing up, is there a reason that all other scripts would be there except this one?

Comment: @Reeggiie Check the file hierarchy. It is difficult to say just by looking at the path without the folder structure.

Comment: @Sushanth-- You were right, I checked the file hierarchy and the jquery-ui.js file was not there. I downloaded and included it, and now it works.  I was missing the file like you thought. If you put this as an answer ill chose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is the file is missing from the hierarchy used on the particular page or project.

The best way to check this out is to use chrome developer tools to see if the script appears in the `Sources` tab.

If it does not appear then check if the script is included in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have a script tag for `jquery-ui`

```
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```